# D3 zoom behavior - mouseup event not firing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseevent, zooming

I'm trying to have D3 pan & zoom as in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/richardwestenra/129f64bfa2b0d48d27c9):

It works except for releasing the zoom/pan on `mouseup()` - once I click, there's no way to stop panning without reloading the page. Here's the piece that calls the zoom function, which in turn is identical to the example:

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("id", "scatter")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([1, 10]).on("zoom", zoom))
```

I've been looking through the D3 source code and `mouseup()` never gets called, in contrast to `mousedown()` and `mousemove()` which respond to the respective events:

> ```
> function mousedown() {
>   var target = this,
>         event_ = event.of(target, arguments),
>         eventTarget = d3.event.target,
>         moved = 0,
>         w = d3.select(d3_window).on("mousemove.zoom", mousemove).on("mouseup.zoom", mouseup),
>         l = location(d3.mouse(target)),
>         selectEnable = d3_event_userSelectSuppress("zoom");
>     function mousemove() {
>     moved = 1;
>     translateTo(d3.mouse(target), l);
>     dispatch(event_);
>     }
>     function mouseup() {
>       if (moved) d3_eventCancel();
>       w.on("mousemove.zoom", null).on("mouseup.zoom", null);
>       selectEnable();
>       if (moved && d3.event.target === eventTarget) d3_eventSuppress(w, "click.zoom");
>     }
> }
> ```

I'm using D3.v3, whereas the example uses D3.vs2, so perhaps the code changed - but I haven't been able to find any useful hint. I'm new to javascript, so this may of course be a different issue altogether.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this "It almost works except for releasing the zoom on mouseup". It appears to work just like the d3 pan + zoom example.

Comment: It fails to release on mouseup(), so once I click I'm panning forever. Clarified above.

Comment: Hmm. Do you mean that it keeps dragging even though you've released the button on your mouse? That doesn't happen to me. The only thing I notice is that the cursor appears like a panning cursor, but everything works as I would expect - I don't get stuck panning.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, keeps dragging after mouse button release. I've copied the example (which does indeed work) but am using different (proprietary) data, and, not surprisingly, everything works identically - except for the mouseup() issue. Wondering if me using D3.vs3 might cause this, or if there's anything else I should look into. Traced it through the D3 source code as outlined above.

Comment: Could you show us an example where this occurs? We don't necessarily need to see your data as long as we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Reduced to essentials, I'm using this within Django: http://bl.ocks.org/InfusiveIntelligence/8392526 - turns out there was a conflict with a debug toolbar that seems to have disabled the mouseup() event. Works fine now once I disable the toolbar.